# how do i save a excel spreadsheet after editing it in access 2007 in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to have Access 2007 open an Excel spreadsheet, add data to the cells, and then save the spreadsheet.  I have a button in an Access 2007 form which activates the following code.  Here is what I have so far, but every "save command" doesn't work.  Does any one have any idea what to use?

```
Private Sub buttonExcel_Click()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    ' Create a New Excel WorkBook
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Optional, Open a current Workbook from a file directory
    oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\test.xlsx")

    ' Make the Excel Workbook visible to the users
    oExcel.Visible = True

    ' Define the Workbook from Excel
    Set oBook = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook

    ' Define the Workskeet from the Workbook (1="Sheet1", 2="Sheet2", etc...)
    Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Write Data to the Worksheet (Block "A1" is the first row, first column)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"

    ' Save the Excel Workbook
    oExcel.SaveAs ("Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\test.xlsx") ' DOESNT WORK
    oExcel("Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\test.xlsx").Save ' DOESNT WORK
    oBook.SaveAs ("Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\test.xlsx") ' DOESNT WORK
    oBook("Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\test.xlsx").Save ' DOESNT WORK

    ' Closes Excel as asks to save the Workbook
    oExcel.Workbooks.Close

    ' Quit Excel
    'oExcel.Quit
End Sub
```

Thanx!

Comment: `oBook.Save` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub buttonExcel_Click()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("Z:\08_Volume Management\" & _
                                 "ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\test.xlsx")
    oExcel.Visible = True

    Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"

    oBook.Save
    oBook.Close
    'or...
    'oBook.Close True 'True = save changes

    oExcel.Quit

End Sub
```